# Clarification on safe http methods

Tags: http-method

I have doubt that we have safe and unsafe http methods. Safe method in its specification states that it don't alter server state. Then my question is what will be the outcome if we use safe method for creating or changing some resource. Please give me more clarification this

Comment: Well, that totally depends on how you implement the respective handler on the server. You can (but probably shouldn't) have `GET` requests that alter the server state, you can have `POST` requests that don't alter the server state ...

Comment: That is, its only a specification. We can use and implement these methods as we wish, then server shouldn't complain on these, right?